# Question about NotebookSecurity and TrustedPath

Tags: notebook-security

I have multiple CDF files that are linear algebra examples with dynamic entries via `InputField`s. An example of a single cell of a matrix is as follows:

```
InputField[Dynamic[a11, Function[If[NumberQ[#] && #=!=Null && Abs[#] < 50, a11 = #]]], FieldSize->3]
```

I use `NumberQ` instead of the `Number` to allow for input of fractions, such as `1/2`, instead of having to put in a decimal equivalent.

Now when I would execute the notebook and test there, I had no issues. But after exporting as Web Embeddable, and then try inputting a fraction, I get the following:

[image: EnableDynamic]

I looked through the documentation on [`NotebookSecurity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html#1392241571) and [a post on MSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38799/unexpected-design-of-protection-against-dynamic-content) that kind of explains this message. I'm just wondering if someone could explain how to get around this caution message so that the file is always trusted no matter what, such as with `TrustByDefault`. I have very narrow knowledge of Mathematica, so I'm not really sure how to apply what is given in the documentation.

Another part of this question I guess is if it is even a good idea to try to get around the caution? Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: If the file is by default in one of the `Dynamic[Column[
  ToFileName /@ 
   CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions", 
     "TrustedPath"}]]]` directories it will be trusted and you won't get the popup. If it is in one of the `Dynamic[Column[
  ToFileName /@ 
   CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions", 
     "UntrustedPath"}]]]` directories you will always get the popup. If it is in neither it relies on the value of `TrustByDefault`

Comment: If someone places the file in an untrusted directory it will give you the warning and I don't think you can get around that as the file-creator.

Comment: @user6014 If the directories are not listed like you said, is it possible to change the value of `TrustByDefault`?

Comment: it looks like it is possible to change the `TrustByDefault` value in CDF Player but not as easy as one would hope.. see http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/616768?p_p_auth=MYuygPH9

Comment: @user6014 I appreciate the link. I'll see what I can do, or just have my boss get over it ;)

Comment: it's a shame that it is a minor annoyance, but the security risks with dynamic functionality do exist so we should be appreciative of the safeguard :) perhaps they will give us more control over it in future versions